# Подскажите библиотеки для сжатия изображений и видео

Tags: c++

Подскажите хорошие библиотеки на c++ для сжатия изображений и видео, желательно минимум настроек (сжатие массива пикселей в jpg с возможностью выбора степени потерь, получение из jpg снова массив пикселей, для видео аналогично), чем меньше размер либы, тем лучше

Answer (score 1):

[FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org) для видео. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) для изображений.

Answer (score 1):

Для картинок - [libjpeg](http://libjpeg.sourceforge.net/). Библиотека хотя и на С, но зато меньше некуда. Для видео - любой специлизированный фреймворк, если требуется именно mjpeg, либо что-то ещё. А можете вообще сжимать кадры тем же libjpeg и писать их всех в один файл с расширением, например, `*.mmf` (my mega format). Соответственно считывать и декодировать - в обратном порядке. Дёшево и сердито.

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте.
Попробуйте через CUDA, OpenCV, BGL.

Comment: CUDA большая, требует драйвера, да и не специализирована под эти задачи...

Comment: @armen krokodil, а что это за BGL? Приведите, пожалуйста, ссылку.